# Find all HTML table rows in PHP with regexp

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

Trying to find all HTML <table> rows with this operator, but nothing:

```
preg_match_all("#<tr[^>]*>.*</tr>#", $content, $matches);
```

what's wrong?

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1338999) DON'T USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS TO PARSE HTML!

Comment: I do wonder if we should be able to close questions with a canned 'HTML/Regexp' reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any regex will have trouble with nested tables, unless you get into complicated recursive expressions.

Try this instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$matches = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tr");
$count = $matches->length;
```

Comment: And what if I want look into HTML between <tr> tags after that?

Comment: Since `$matches` is a DOMNodeList, each node has a property `childNodes` which is another DOMNodeList of its children.

Comment: @Kolink Well i may case when i have to parse an invalid HTML the DOMDocument is failed to parse.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all ('#<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>#s')
```

Added the "s" flag, so that it also matches newlines, a question mark to the match (lazy), and also added parenthesis  (to capture the group).

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have a lot more success with a [PHP HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).